# Repeat image to form a pattern in python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library, image-manipulation

I have an image as input, It can be hexagon, square, or any polygon shape. The image is in png format. After the input, the image should generate a new image using only the input image with no space in between them. I am attaching a sample image below for clarity.

Input image to output image:
[image: Input image to output image]

I have tried to work on it but my output is not as expected.

What I could achieve:

[image: What I could achieve]

Can anyone guide me on how to work on its steps, code or what is it called?

Comment: See https://www.redblobgames.com/grids/hexagons/

Comment: Thanks, @fmw42 but this limited only to hexagon shape. As i said the image can be any polygon shape.

Comment: Here's a little toy to explore: https://pastebin.com/eMF1uZ3w The input should be an image with a single tile on white background (just roughly cut it out with big enough margin around it). Then play around with the sliders, and press any key (or close window) to move to next step.

Comment: The first problem to solve is to isolate a single tile, and determine a mask for it. This is made difficult by your example having a lot of JPEG artifacts, so the borders are not clear. Since the desired output sometimes have a different background colour from that of the tile, I try to mitigate this by getting a straight enough controur, and using to draw a border around the shape. | Once you have the tile, you need to find the right step size for each pattern. It has to be 2D for both row and column increases.

Comment: For example, for the hexagon you have in your second image, each second column has to have its origin adjusted down by half the height of the tile. Also the spacing between columns needs to be adjusted to the left somewhat (the exact math to determine this amount for a hexagon is left to the reader). The specific offsets will differ based on the shape of the tile.

Comment: @DanMašek as I mentioned the input images are in png format, I tried with what you suggested but it isn't going to work for all the shapes. Can there be a method where we take the image print it on an empty image, Move our input image around the first printed input image and repeat this till there is no space left? SEAMLESS repeating of the image to form a pattern.

Comment: @DanMašek btw it was a nice implementation i learnt few methods from your answer. But it dint solved the purporse

Comment: This is for example what I get from the top-right sample input: https://i.imgur.com/R6AW7lG.png (after adjusting the sliders appropriately). To automatically determine the step sizes, you'd need to develop some sort of heuristic specific to each sort of shape you want to handle (and identify those as well), each potentially with a specific set of orientations that you want to handle. | Glad that helped, that was the intent. Don't really feel like going further than that tho, have other things to work on :)

Comment: I suppose you could also determine it brute force, by rendering the possible combinations of offsets and finding out which one gives you minimum overall size with no overlap. That would probably be quite slow tho.

Comment: @DanMašek got your point, Will keep on trying. Thank you!

Comment: No problem. If you have clean PNG images of the single tiles, it would be useful to include them with your question. Currently i had to extract the samples to work with using an image editor, and their poor quality made it harder. Ideal input for this would be a clean lossless tile image either with an accompanying mask, or even better alpha transparency channel that only has the tile contents visible. | Anyway, process what you learned here, and then perhaps make a new question about determining the spacing automatically (with good code sample and input images).